# ProgressDialog is not displayed

Tags: android

I have an Async Task getting me some data from the web. Async Task works fine and I want a Progress Dialog Spinner to be displayed while the data is being procured from the web.The Progress Dialog Spinner never shows up. Here is my code:

```
public class JsonHttpParsingActivity extends ListActivity{
private String jsonResult;
private ArrayList nameArray;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    HttpConnection task = new HttpConnection(this);
    AsyncTask<String,Void,String> taskResult = task.execute("Some URL...");
    try {
        jsonResult = taskResult.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            .
            .
            More Code.....
}
}

public class HttpConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Activity m_activity;

protected HttpConnection(Activity activity) {
    setActivity(activity);
  }

  public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
    m_activity = activity;

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(m_activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Wait ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();
  }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String inputLine= "", finalMessage = "";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        String urladdress = params[0];
        URL url = new URL(urladdress);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            finalMessage = finalMessage + inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
        Log.v("finalmessage", ""+finalMessage);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }       
    return finalMessage;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
     progressDialog.setProgress((int) ((values[0] / (float) values[1]) * 100));
     };

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      progressDialog.hide();
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of write a separate method `setActivity(activity)` (Non UI Thread scope)
for starting `ProgressDialog` put the code in `onPreExecute()` (UI Thread) of `AsyncTask`, Because you are trying to show it in non UI thread.

Try this,

```
protected HttpConnection(Activity activity) {
   m_activity = activity;
  }

Override 
protected void onPreExecute(String result){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(m_activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Wait ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call progress bar from onPreExecute() function

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine and tested:

```
    public class HttpConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Activity m_activity;

    protected HttpConnection(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(m_activity);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Wait ...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

    super.onPreExecute();
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String inputLine= "", finalMessage = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            String urladdress = params[0];
            URL url = new URL(urladdress);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                finalMessage = finalMessage + inputLine;
            }
            in.close();
            Log.v("finalmessage", ""+finalMessage);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }       
        return finalMessage;
    }


    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
          progressDialog.hide();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, Its not working..!  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(m_activity); this line gives exception.. Because m_activity has not initialized.

Comment: Initialized m_activity in the constructor and put the code from setActivity() in onPreExecute()(UI Thread), but still no Progress Dialog.

Comment: @user370305: Just use any reference to a `Context` instance. Since your `AsyncTask` is implemented as inner class, you might as well use `JsonHttpParsingActivity.this`

Comment: @MH. - I knew, all these things. This comment for Vinothkumar Arputharaj to point the line for which his code not working. I already put my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the AsyncTask from another method in the activity. My guess is that right now, you call it in the onCreate method of the activity. Since the activity is still building, this can give you exceptions. A thing I once tried when I had this issue, is starting the asynchronous task from the onPostCreate method of the activity.